# Using Thread.Sleep, while using program

Tags: c#, winforms, sleep

When using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(n)`, I understand that it blocks the thread of the program, which result in the program being inaccessible; eg: Not being able to click buttons, or bring up other forms.

So what my question is, is there any other alternative that I could use that would just pause my one method, but still allow me to use buttons, and open other forms and such?

The code that I am using is messy becuase I have been using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)` but here it is:

```
while(Reader.Read() != null)
{
    ApplicationPort.WriteLine(line);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
}
```

Line is just a string that is bein updated earlier on the code, the rate that it updates is too fast for what I am trying to accomplish so I am trying to slow the program down by using `Sleep`. And ApplicationPort, is just a `SerialPort`

This code is not allowing me to use other object while it is sleeping, so is there an alternative to this where I can still use the rest of my program while the while just the `while` loop sleeps?

Comment: Why do you need to sleep the thread at all?

Comment: Use a Timer instead, and have it call whatever code you want to execute

Comment: Becausethe rate that the SerialPort is writing to the port is much too fast for what I am trying to do. I would like to slow everything down, and be able to use the program while it is slowed down also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your method in separate thread, and you will be free to pause/resume as much as you want...

Take a look to the [Thread class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a while loop and `Application.DoEvents`  Something like:

```
while(Reader.Read() != null)
{
    ApplicationPort.WriteLine(line);
    var endDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);
    while (DateTime.Now() < endDate)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

However this is "hacky" and you should be following ArsenMkrt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider adding a timer to your app and print the line when the timer hits. This would not tie up your app.

An example here [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)